# AWSS3 What are the best strategies of bucket location for video uploading?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, awss3transfermanager, awss3transferutility

I have configured a bucket on Amazon and I use CloudFront. I upload images and videos on it.

Even though my videos are max 15 sec and I compress them (with `AVAssetExportSession` in `AVAssetExportPreset640x480` format + `shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse` set to `true`) before sending them, it seems too long to upload (sometimes more than 1,5 min).

I was wondering if I should configure several buckets in several locations in the world in order to upload the user video to the nearest bucket and reduce the upload time.

Any other suggestion is very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things you can try:

1. You can enable "S3 Transfer acceleration" on you s3 bucket. CloudFront is helpful when downloading/accessing images. This will help in uploading. This gives more benefit when bucket location is far off from uploading location.
2. Second solution can be as u suggested.. And then you can create rules on bucket to automatically transfer to another Global bucket. But this makes upload asynchronus i.e. even though you have uploaded video into the bucket; still some users might not see video for some time. And this global bucket should be in region which is closes to your MOST users. Also, you need to use CloudFront here which connects to global bucket.

Comment: Thanks, I'll start with the 1st suggestion and see how it improves the speed :)

Comment: I'm not sure... :) I see no difference in the upload speed. But I did go on the Amazon page to compare speed uploads and it did not seem it would make a big difference. So right now I don't know if I implemented it wrong or if the difference is just not significant.

Comment: As mentioned in my comment; improvement will depend on distance between your bucket location and video original location. More the distance; more the improvement. Also, I can understand your customers viewing videos can be worldwide; but are people uploading videos also worldwide ! If yes, then this will give huge benefits.. If uploading video happens only from one location; then you can simply create global bucket nearest to your uploading location.. All the best :)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to answer your query part "I was wondering if I should configure several buckets in several locations in the world in order to upload the user video to the nearest bucket and reduce the upload time."

Actually there is no need to create multiple buckets in different regions because firstly you can not have duplicate bucket names, now even if you create buckets with different names based on the regions , it will be really a bad idea to manage all videos on a central region.

Now coming to the solution : You can Enable Transfer acceleration on S3 bucket : [S3 Bucket Transfer Acceleration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/transfer-acceleration.html)